# Keyboard not working on Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

Tags: usb, hardware, power, pi-2, keyboard

I'm trying to connect my **PS/2** keyboard to the **Raspberry Pi Model B**.  So I went out and bought myself a **PS/2 to USB** adapter hoping that it would work.

Here's an image of the adapter below:

[image]

And here is a picture of the keyboard I'm using:

[image]

It's an **IBM Keyboard Model KB-7953** With **5v** and **200mA**.

Comment if there is any more information you need to know to see what the problem is.

Comment: Did you test the keyboard and pigtail combo in another system to make sure it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That type of converter just wires pins to pins. Legacy USB ports are able to notice that it's a PS/2 keyboard and change their behaviour.

[image]

The RPi USB port doesn't have the support for the PS/2 combatibility

You need one with a translation chip like [this one from adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/products/971)

[image]